# Riddle : Lend me your ear; I love quarrels

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Sitting in my star chamber, I make things prime.
I look like you, but upset.
Dukes, Bishops or Angels - I am ahead of all of them.
Ah, I see the end; I am very old. In short, I have the end; I keep the old.
I am in a parade. I am in a ruler. I am in a hunt. I am in sugar.
Lend me your ear; I excel in quarrels.
Destroy me; I can burn you and start a new different puzzle.

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this puzzle maybe you are:

> Arch

Sitting in my star chamber, I make things prime

> Arch is a hidden word in st*ar ch*amber.
>  Synonyms for arch (as adjective) are principal, superior or premier.

I look like you, but upset

> An arch in architecture looks like an inverted U

Dukes, Bishops or Angels - I am ahead of all of them

> E.g. Archduke Franz Ferdinand, Archbishop of Canterbury and Archangel Gabriel

Ah, I see the end; I am very old. In short, I have the end; I keep the old

> Ah - the end of ah is the end of arch
>  I am very old - archaic.  Arch. is and abbreviation of archaic (very old)
>  I don't think I've got all this.

I am in a parade. I am in a ruler. I am in a hunt. I am in sugar

> Parade - march,  ruler - patriarch,  hunt - research ,  sugar - starch
>  (Starches -  complex carbohydrates - are polysaccharides or long sugar molecule chains)

Lend me your ear; I excel in quarrels

> Arch can mean deliberately or affectedly playful, teasing or pointed.

Destroy me; I can burn you and start a new different puzzle

> Rearrange (destroy) arch becomes char which means partially burn
>   And start a new puzzle - charades, a parlor game
>  Also hope you start a new puzzle as yours are arch meaning premier!

Comment: That's the correct answer! Just a remark: the "old" clues have some trickier wordplay involved. Hint: what do you do to get from arch to archaic?

Comment: I believe that "ah, I see" = aic, added on to "the end" of arch to get archaic.

Comment: @pime Exactly! And what about "keep the old"?

Comment: In short I have is ive which at the end gives archive :)